# Categorize custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-taxonomy

I'm currently building a tv show database and have structured the site this way so far:

Custom post type called "Series" is used to post the main TV Show information, with custom taxonomies (genre, year, directors...etc). I also got child series posts as seasons:

The Walking dead (Series)
-- The Walking Dead Season 1 as child

[image]

I've got another post type called "Episodes" that is used to post individual episode information, then I'm linking the episode to the tv show + season using [Post 2 Posts](https://wordpress.org/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin.

If I link the episodes to the main TV Show, I can query them using `'connected_type'=> 'posts_to_series'`, but If I link them to individual seasons, they don't show up.

I need get each season of a tv show and list posts linked to them, thank you!

Comment: It's hard for me to understand exactly what you are trying to do but if you have the ID of the season CPT, couldn't you just do `$related_posts = p2p_type( 'posts_to_series' )->get_related( $season_id );` to get the posts you have linked to a specific season?